# Populate empty values from another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let us say that I have two SQL tables

**Employee Recognition Table**

| Employee Id | Reward Date | Coupon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | null |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 | null |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 | null |
| 2 | 2/1/2020 | null |
| 2 | 2/2/2020 | null |
| 3 | 2/2/2020 | null |

**Coupons**

| Employee Id | Coupon |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | COUPON1 |
| 1 | COUPON2 |
| 1 | COUPON3 |
| 2 | COUPON4 |

What I want to do is allot coupons to all the employee uniquely, example

- employee 1 has three coupons so they should be allotted
- employee 2 just has 1 coupon so 1 should get allotted
- employee 3 has none

So the output should be something like

**Employee Recognition Table Updated**

| Employee Id | Reward Date | Coupon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | COUPON1 |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 | COUPON2 |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 | COUPON3 |
| 2 | 2/1/2020 | COUPON4 |
| 2 | 2/2/2020 | null |
| 3 | 2/2/2020 | null |

Also the table contains a lot of records both tables above 100k records so wondering what a performant query can look like. I have thought about using lateral joins but the speed seems to be the issue there.

Comment: Please tag with exact RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select * except(pos)
from (
  select Employee_Id, Reward_Date, 
    row_number() over(partition by Employee_Id order by Reward_Date) pos
  from recognitions
)
left join (
  select Employee_Id, Coupon, 
    row_number() over(partition by Employee_Id order by Coupon) pos
  from coupons
)
using (Employee_Id, pos)
-- order by Employee_Id, Reward_Date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]